# How to run raw SQL inside a Django unittest

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-unittest

How do you run a raw SQL query inside a Django unittest?

I find if I use a [cursor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors), it seems to break the unittest's transaction so that any changes to the Sqlite database aren't reverted at the end of the unittest.

My unittest looks like:

```
class Tests(TestCase):

    def test_first(self):

        print('FIRST:', MyModel.objects.all().count())

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM myapp_mymodel;')
            r = cursor.fetchone()
        finally:
            cursor.close()

        MyModel.objects.create(name='abc')

    def test_second(self):

        print('SECOND:', MyModel.objects.all().count())
```

and it currently outputs the unexpected:

```
FIRST: 0
SECOND: 1
```

and if I comment out the cursor code, then it outputs the correct result:

```
FIRST: 0
SECOND: 0
```

What black magic is going on here? Is `connection.cursor` not support inside Django's special unittest transaction?

Comment: if there is an error you should post a full stacktrace. The accepted method of running raw queries in django is using the `raw()` method call. However even that is not needed in the test_case you have shown. A much simpler ORM query would work nicely here

Comment: Could you please show your imports as well? Thanks.